# How to Read from Mongodb secondary server using Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am facing an issue in yiisoft/ yii2-mongodb extension I am using three mongodb servers one primary and two secondaries but i am getting an error as below while fetching data from secondary servers.

The server gives below error
    “name”: “MongoDB Exception”,
    “message”: “not master”,
    “code”: 10107,
    “type”: “yii\mongodb\Exception

```
my connection is as below
‘components’ => [
       ‘mongodb’ => [
           ‘class’ => ‘\yii\mongodb\Connection’,
           ‘dsn’ => ‘mongodb://xxx:27017,xxx:27017,xxx:27017/?replicaSet=p&connectTimeoutMS=480000&socketTimeoutMS=520000&readPreference=secondary’,
       ],
]
```

Comment: {
"name": "MongoDB Exception",
"message": "not master",
"code": 10107,
"type": "yii\\mongodb\\Exception",
"file": "/home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php",
"line": 192,
"stack-trace": [
"#0 /home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php(357): yii\\mongodb\\Command->execute()",
"#1 /home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Collection.php(153): yii\\mongodb\\Command->createIndexes('auth_item', Array)",
"#2 /home/ubuntu/panelapi/common/components/MongodbManager.php(59): yii\\mongodb\\Collection->createIndex(Array, Array)"
],

Comment: "previous": {
"name": "Exception",
"message": "not master",
"code": 10107,
"type": "MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\CommandException",
"file": "/home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php",
"line": 186,
"stack-trace": [
"#0 /home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php(186): MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager->executeCommand('panelmanagement', Object(MongoDB\\Driver\\Command), Object(MongoDB\\Driver\\ReadPreference))",
"#1 /home/ubuntu/panelapi/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php(357): yii\\mongodb\\Command->execute()",
]
}
}

Answer (score -2):

Try to add options to your config like this:

```
'mongodb' => [
   'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mongodb://xxx:27017,xxx:27017,xxx:27017/?replicaSet=p&connectTimeoutMS=480000&socketTimeoutMS=520000&readPreference=secondary',
   'options' => [
        'replicaSet' => 'p'
    ]
]
```

Furthermore, you can add connection options like **connectTimeoutMS** directly in options array

Comment: I don't think it will work we can pass as in string or options both works same right?

Comment: It should work same, as Yii creates new Manager instance - see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php - and pass options as the second parameter (the will overwrite same uri params). have you tried options array?